# Position of 'was'

Tags: word-order

I know this is correct:

> I don't know what the problem **that he was trying to solve** was.

But is this?

> I don't know what the problem was **that he was trying to solve**.

I think the latter is incorrect. However, the problem with the former is that when the extra part (in bold) describing the object (in this case "problem") is long it makes it harder to construct the sentence correctly (you have to remember about that poor lonely "was" and not forget to place it at the end), especially when you have no time to think about it before you say it. Consider:

> I don't know what the problem **that Mike and his brother spent the entire day yesterday trying to solve** was.

Is there a better (more convenient) way to say it?

Comment: Are you sure you mean "that ***we was*** trying to solve"?

Comment: With "he" substituted for "we", I would prefer the second version.  Though you could say "I don't know what problem Mike and his brother spent the entire day yesterday trying to solve."

Comment: The second version is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Those are all correct. It's okay to extrapose the relative clause there. You could also try: *I don't know what problem Mike and his brother spent the entire day yesterday trying to solve.*